# PHP GD Library and uploaded files

Tags: php, file-upload, gd

I'm working on a project where I upload an image (jpg) and manipulate it using the PHP GD library.

I know that I can use GD functions to edit an image resource (created from imagecreatefromjpeg()) but I was wondering if there was a way I could use the file uploaded in the $_FILES array directly with the GD library. One solution I thought of was saving the uploaded file, pushing it into imagecreatefromjpeg, then deleting it afterwards.

This seems cluinky though, is there a more efficient solution?

I'm still a bit new to PHP so I'm not sure as to how files are stored in the $_FILES array. I hope I'm making sense here. Thanks.

Comment: you can work with the temp file created, without saving it

Comment: ^^^ That should be the answer right there :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
// do gd operations on $img
imagejpeg($img, '/path/to/target');
```

You'll have to use `imagecreatefrom` in some form or another, and you can use it directly on the uploaded file. Then just save the result of your manipulations using `imagejpeg`. The uploaded file in `tmp_name` will we thrown away automatically.

Having said that, you *should* save the original somewhere. It's always good to have it around for later use.

Comment: Wish I could upvote you twice.  First for the correct answer reading directly from the temp file, and again for suggesting stashing the original somewhere.  It's almost always worthwhile to do so.

Comment: Ah I was thinking something along these lines. Thanks!

Comment: i have tried this...but still get an error: imagecreatefrompng(): 'C:\wamp64\tmp\php6157.tmp' is not a valid PNG file in ... I have an array of images uploaded, as you see, I have a tmp, but still an error... any help?